# User Add/login form Issue

Tags: php, mysql

I made a simple User Add/login form .But i cannot extract or add data to database using array and need simple procedure.

```
<?php
 //User_Add_Page
    if(isset($_POST['userid'],$_POST['username'],$_POST['password'],$_POST['sex'],$_POST['desig']))
    {

       include("connect.php");
       $badchars='!@Â£$%^&*()+=-][\;/.,`~<>?:"|{} \'';
       $userid=$_POST['userid'];
       $username=$_POST['username'];
       $password=$_POST['password'];
       $sex=$_POST['sex'];
       $desig=$_POST['desig'];
       $errors=array();

               if(empty($userid)&& empty($username) && empty($password) && empty($sex) && empty($design))
               {
                        $errors[]= "All Fields Require";
               }
                else if($userid=="")
               {
                        $errors[]= "Enter User ID";
               }

               else if (strpbrk($userid, $badchars) !== false)
               {

                       $errors[]= 'INVALID User ID...';
               }
               else  if(strlen($userid)<5 && $username != "")
               {
                       $errors[]='User ID Must be Greater than 5 Characters';
               }
               else  if(is_numeric ($userid))
               {

                      $errors[]= 'User ID Must Conatin Both letters AND character';
               }

               else  if(strlen($userid)>20 && $username != "")
               {

                     $errors[]= 'User ID Must be Less Than 20 Characters';
               }

               else if($username=="")
               {

                       $errors[]= "Enter username";
               }
               else if(strlen($username)>30)
               {

                      $errors[]= "Enter username less than 30 char.";
               }

               else if(!ctype_alpha(str_replace(' ','',$username)))//search alphabetic char. from username
               {

                     $errors[]='Name Must be Character Only';
               }
               else if($password == "")
               {

                     $errors[]= 'Please Enter Password';
               }

               else  if(strlen($password)<5 && $password != "")
               {

                     $errors[]= 'Password Must Be Greater Than 5 Characters';
               }
               else  if($desig == "")
               {

                     $errors[]= 'Please Enter Designation';
        }


            else if(empty($errors))
            {
                       $write=("INSERT INTO adduser VALUES ('','$userid','$username','$password','$sex','$desig')");


                       $time = 1; //Time (in seconds) to wait.
                   $url = "add_user_process.php"; //Location to send to.
               header("Refresh: $time; url=$url");
            }
}



 ?>
```

Comment: Instead of `else if(empty($errors))` you need to do `else if(count($errors) <= 0)` this will work.

Comment: count doesn't work....Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\add_user2.php on line 79..it gives this error

Comment: check the brackets may be u have leave or add an extra brackets.

Comment: Ome more queestion,,I cnnot display Form error,Like if i doesn't enter username,,than,,it should echo out "Enter username" ??

Comment: You need to echo them on the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
 else if(empty($errors))
            {
                       $write=("INSERT INTO adduser VALUES ('','$userid','$username','$password','$sex','$desig')");

                      mysqli_query($write,Your_connection_string)
                       $time = 1; //Time (in seconds) to wait.
                   $url = "add_user_process.php"; //Location to send to.
               header("Refresh: $time; url=$url");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

After your "INSERT INTO" you have to specify mysql_query object ,
    like $result = mysql_query($write);

Like this ,

```
 $write="INSERT INTO adduser VALUES ('','$userid','$username','$password','$sex','$desig')";
 $result = mysql_query($write);
```

Comment: Ome more queestion,,I cnnot display Form error,Like if i doesn't enter username,,than,,it should echo out "Enter username" ??

Comment: first thankuh for ur help..but the link u share ,i cant understand..so imade a change instead of using array i tried to used normal global variable to display the form validation on the same page..but i doesn't echo out anything...but no errors,,i have tried this the whole days...

Comment: I mean to say like this ,  `<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","*****","*****","my_project");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
} 

$error  =   false;
$errorMsg   =   "";

if (strlen($_POST['product_name']) < 5 ) {
    $error  =   true;
    $errorMsg. = "name is too short";
} 
elseif (strlen($_POST['product_name']) > 10) {
    $error  =   true;
    $errorMsg. = "name is too long";
} 
?>`